# How to bring the next line to the end of the first line using awk, separated by a comma?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep, bioinformatics

I have downloaded some sequences from a publicly available database in `.fa` format. I want to generate a `.csv` file that contains the name of the sequence, and its length, separated by a comma.
This is how the input file is:

```
>cel-let-7-5p MIMAT0000001 Caenorhabditis elegans let-7-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUU
>cel-let-7-3p MIMAT0015091 Caenorhabditis elegans let-7-3p
CUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACC
>cel-lin-4-5p MIMAT0000002 Caenorhabditis elegans lin-4-5p
UCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGA
>cel-lin-4-3p MIMAT0015092 Caenorhabditis elegans lin-4-3p
ACACCUGGGCUCUCCGGGUACC
>cel-miR-1-5p MIMAT0020301 Caenorhabditis elegans miR-1-5p
CAUACUUCCUUACAUGCCCAUA
```

To select the first entry of the header line, and to print the size of the read on the next line, I am using the following command:

`grep -A 1 "^>" file_name.fa | awk '{print($1); getline; print length($0)}'`

Here's what I'm getting.
The output:

```
>cel-let-7-5p
22
>cel-let-7-3p
22
>cel-lin-4-5p
21
>cel-lin-4-3p
22
>cel-miR-1-5p
22
```

However, in my desired output, I want to make a `.csv` file that can be exported to Excel/R/python.
Expected output:

```
cel-let-7-5p,22
cel-let-7-3p,22
cel-lin-4-5p,21
cel-lin-4-3p,22
cel-miR-1-5p,22
```

Is there any way I can do this? I am unable to find relevant help online.

Comment: Avoid the use of `getline()`. See my answer for explanations

Comment: Can the sequence span more than a single line?

Comment: If you plan to do something with the input in python, why not ask for help to write the python code to read it as-is instead of asking for help to write an awk script or similar to convert it to CSV for python to read?

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) ([avoid the use of `getline()`](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) where's it's not absolutely required):

```
$ awk '
    /^>/{sub(/^>/, "");printf "%s,", $1;next}    # process lines starting with '>'
    {print length()}                             # other lines
' file_name.fa
```

##### Output

```
cel-let-7-5p,22
cel-let-7-3p,22
cel-lin-4-5p,21
cel-lin-4-3p,22
cel-miR-1-5p,22
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only ever a single sequence line after each header line, you can move the sequence to the end of the header and then use `awk` to extract the first part of the header and the length of the sequence at the end.

With `paste`, read lines and paste them into two tab-delimited columns, then pass them to `awk` for processing:

```bash
$ paste - - <file | awk -v OFS=, '{ sub("^>",""); print $1, length($NF) }'
cel-let-7-5p,22
cel-let-7-3p,22
cel-lin-4-5p,21
cel-lin-4-3p,22
cel-miR-1-5p,22
```

The `sub()` command deletes the initial `>` character.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[> ]' '{ printf ("%s", NR%2?$2",":length() ORS ) }' infile
cel-let-7-5p,22
cel-let-7-3p,22
cel-lin-4-5p,21
cel-lin-4-3p,22
cel-miR-1-5p,22
```

The code is defining two set of space   and `>` characters as the field separetor then with a Ternary operator `(condition ? do-if-true : do-if-false)` we are checking if the line number is the *odd* number (`NR%2` will return 1 if the line-number was odd) then it will chose to print column #2 + a comma after that `$2","`; else if the line-number was *even* number (`NR%2` will return 0 if line-number was even) then it will chose to print the `length()` of the current line + Output Record Separetor (ORS, which is default a newline character).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I might be asking for too much, but can you give an explanation of the code? e.g. I don't know what -F does or what "%s" stands for. Or maybe direct me to some source? I'm a beginner and I don't know much about this.

Comment: @HrishikeshHardikar please take a look into the [`man awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk), sections "**Options**" for the `-F` and "**The printf Statement**" for the `%s`;

Answer (score 0):

The ideal tool for this job is the N option of sed command:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n/,/g' infile |sed 's/^.//'

cel-let-7-5p,22
cel-let-7-3p,22
cel-lin-4-5p,21
cel-lin-4-3p,22
cel-miR-1-5p,22
```

(the second sed removes the leading angle brackets)

Comment: Are you proposing that the user tags this on to the end of their existing pipeline to create a `grep`+`awk`+`sed`+`sed` pipeline?  Note too that `sed` can apply multiple commands to the input: `sed -e N -e 's/\n/,/' -e 's/.//'` (I've also removed unnecessary bits here).

Answer (score 0):

```bash
awk '/^>/ {a=$1; next} {print a,length}' OFS=, file
```